# Is "pure XCOPY deployment" of an ASP.NET application possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

After copying an ASP.NET web application in some `wwwroot` subdirectory, you still have to use IIS admin to "configure the directory as an application" (set the application pool, etc). In IIS integrated mode, lots of options can be set directly in web.config (authentication methods, default document, etc.), but I have not yet found a "*treat this directory as an application with the following app pool*" setting.

Is it still necessary to use the IIS admin tool or do newer IIS versions support "true" XCOPY deployment of ASP.NET web applications?

Comment: saying "true" you mean deploying to the server which *has not ever* before had an application installed ?

Comment: I mean "deploying to a server which has not ever before had *this* application installed".

Comment: Obviously not, it's a chicken or egg problem. You need to male it an App folder before any config is read or processed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The config is read in the wwwroot folder, which could be a starting point.